# How to set a handle on GUI form load in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am new to `Matlab`, so apologies if it's a stupid question.

I would like to set the contents of a `popupmenu` on `form load`. That is, as soon as a form is loaded, the contents of the drop down list reflect the contents of a particular variable.

I am trying to set the popupmenu from the function `figure1_CreateFcn` - However it one of the comments when the function is created says "**there are handles not created until after all CreateFcns called**" - And the code gives "**Attempt to reference field of non-structure array**." error.

How can I set the popupmenu on form load?

---Code---

```
set(handles.pnlLinks,'Visible','on')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using GUIDE:

There is a function called OpeningFcn-> This is the function where you can use the set(handles.pnLinks,...)-function.

For background info:

search for:

> Initialize a GUIDE GUI

within the help browser